# Is it possible to contrain a class from a third-party web service?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constraints

I have a two classes where 1 is inherited. There are a number of other classes similar to Acme123Response with different response classes. I.e. ApplicationInfo.

ApplicationInfo belongs to a third-party web service. The question is, is it possible to add a where constraint to BuyerResponse given that ApplicationInfo and the rest are outside of my immediate control?

```
public class Acme123Response : BuyerResponse<ApplicationInfo>
{
    public Acme123Response(ApplicationInfo response)
        : base(response)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class BuyerResponse<T> : ResponseBase
{
    readonly T _response;

    protected T Response
    {
        get { return _response; }
    }

    protected BuyerResponse(T response)
    {
        _response = response;

        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, constraining BuyerResponse<T> to be a subclass of ApplicationInfo, for example? Then yes you should be able to do that.

Comment: ApplicationInfo is the third-party class. I wanted to constrain T to one of a number of classes from third-parties, maybe using an interface or something. Any detail as to how this might be approached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your comments correctly, then your question is can you define a base interface for classes defined in 3rd party assemblies. AFAIK this isn't possible (even if you could fork the source it's not something I'd want to do): the best I'd think you can do is define wrapper classes/[adapters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) that implement your unifying interface, and then base your generic constraint on that.

This also has the effect of shielding your own implementations from 3rd party classes with an interface, which is generally something you'd want to do anyways.

Comment: I think I understand so create a class MyWrapperClass inheriting ApplicationInfo, with interface IMyWrapperClass